# how do you import a local csv into hive without creating a schema using sqoop

Tags: hive, sqoop

I have a csv in my local directory and i wish to create a hive table of it..The problem is csv has many columns...

Comment: i am a bit new to sqoop..only other option is to manually type in the schema for the table in hive and then import(i was doing that recently)...i was just reading about sqoop create hive table..very helpful if you cld fill me in with the syntax for this

Answer (score 1):

In authors words Sqoop means Sql-to-Hadoop.. you can't use Sqoop to import data from your local to hdfs in any way.

Sqoop (“SQL-to-Hadoop”) is a straightforward command-line tool with the following capabilities:

- Imports individual tables or entire databases to files in HDFS
- Generates Java classes to allow you to interact with your imported data
- Provides the ability to import from SQL databases straight into your Hive data warehouse

For more information follow below links:

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/06/introducing-sqoop/

http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-speed-up-your-hive-queries-in.html